# What should be the correct mysql query for retrieving result like this logic

Tags: mysql

```
***TABLE LEAD***
ID  ||  LID ||  LNAME       ||  STATUS      ||  TIME
------------------------------------------------------
1   ||  22  ||  LA12        ||  SUCCESS     ||  11:40
2   ||  56  ||  LA13        ||  ERROR 1     ||  14:23
3   ||  89  ||  LA45        ||  ERROR 2     ||  18:30
4   ||  100 ||  LA56        ||  SUCCESS     ||  10:20

***Table ACTIVITY***
ID  ||  ACTIDID ||  LNAME   ||   STATUS     ||   TIME
-----------------------------------------------------
1   ||  24      ||  LA12    ||  ERROR 1     ||  11:10
2   ||  25      ||  LA12    ||  ERROR 2     ||  11:11  
3   ||  26      ||  LA12    ||  ERROR 1     ||  11:40
4   ||  58      ||  LA13    ||  ERROR 1     ||  14:23
5   ||  91      ||  LA45    ||  ERROR 2     ||  18:30
6   ||  102     ||  LA56    ||  ERROR 2     ||  10:15
7   ||  103     ||  LA56    ||  ERROR 3     ||  10:20
```

I have two tables (LEAD & Activity), The activity table have multiple activities against leads.

So, I want those rows from LEAD TABLE WHERE LEAD STATUS != LAST ACTIVITY STATUS

### Result should be

```
LNAME
LA12
LA56
```

Comment: Your data and logic are not clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery to determine max id per lname in the activity table, join this on activity table to get the status and join this on lead table on lname to get the lead status. In the where criteria filter those out, where lead and activity statuses are not the same.

```
select l.lname
from lead l
left join (select max(id) as maxid, lname from activity group by lname) m on l.lname=m.lname
left join activity a on m.lname=a.lname and m.maxid=a.id
where a.status<>l.status or a.status is null
```

Comment: To get the status. I do not want to rely on mysql's ability of allowing not full group by clauses and ordering activity table by id in descending order and doing a group by lnae on that. It is not a recommended approach.